# git staging area in shared repository

Tags: git

I have a common environment (Unix VM ) used by many developers via session , they're all working on a shared local repository, do that means that they have the same staging area or everyone has his own staging area ?

Comment: A Git repository contains only one index (aka staging). Each developer should have their own Git repository. Even more, given that you use virtual machines, every developer should use their own virtual machine.

Comment: they all access the same environment under different sessions but we have a shared local repository ( by constraint)

Comment: One repo == one index.

Answer (score 0):

If all of you work on different directory that's mean you all have your own staging area but if you work in the same directory you are going to share your staging area as well.

Comment: by directory you mean local repository ?

Comment: I make a difference between repository and directory. For example if your user1 work on /home/user1/locarepo/ and your user 2 work on /home/user2/localrepo/  its the same repository as all of them link to the same git project but the directory change. By directory i mean the folder where your team member work.